# 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, maven

I've got a maven project, within which is JavaScript project cloned as a git sub-module. So the directory structure looks like `mavenapp/src/main/javascript/[npm project files]`

Inside my package.json, the test looks like this:

```
"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
```

but when I try to run `npm test`, it says

> 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Interestingly, when I clone the javascript project independently I don't get this error. I've tried re-running `npm install`.

NPM version: 5.5.1
Node.js version: 9.3.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57093235/generate-sourcemap-false-issue look at this..

Answer (score 321):

It is an error about **react-scripts** file missing in your `node_modules/` directory at the time of installation.

Check your react-script dependency is avaliable or not in `package.json`.

If not available then add it manually via:

```
npm install react-scripts --save
```

Comment: DO NOT do this, this could cause issues with other projects... you should NOT install react-scripts globally like this. Refer here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2436#issuecomment-306830791

Comment: @RosdiKasim After read your comment, I have realized my error. Now, I have changed the command for the specific project instead of globally(-g).

Comment: Nothing changes for me, still the same error. Running "npm install react-scripts --save" even if succesful doesn't create any folder react-scripts in npm_modules folder. I'm on Windows10

Comment: @RosdiKasim, based on your comment, you should follow the end of the thread on Github. I was running on the same issue and fixed that by doing like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54403797/8719007 (the answer below)

Comment: If using Yarn V2, or Create React-App, you just need to run `yarn install` before `yarn start`.

Comment: Run `yarn install` or `npm install` to fix the issue as this was sufficient in my case.

Answer (score 176):

If `react-scripts` is present in `package.json`, then just type this command

```
npm install
```

If `react-scripts` is not present in `package.json`, then you probably haven't installed it. To do that, run:

```
npm install react-scripts --save
```

Comment: What if I have it in my package.json and also install it, but face the same  problem?

Comment: @Serob_b Sometimes I also have same problem in that case i just run "npm install" and it solves the problem. or you can always delete the node_modules folder by typing rm "-rf node_modules" in terminal and then run "npm install". hope this helps

Comment: This is the complete answer

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 85):

Try:

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm install
```

Wiping `node_modules` first, often tends to fix a lot of weird, package related issues like that in Node.

Comment: yes I have... no difference... For now I've had to just removed the submodule and just paste it in manually.

Comment: Hmm, you're not seeing any errors logged from your `npm install` are you? Try to run an `npm install -f` and see if anything changes. Could be another package that's failing to install and blocking `create-react-app` from installing completely. Forcing an npm install with `-f`, btw, is never a complete solution.... just a troubleshooting step. If anything changes after you run that, then you know there is something wrong with one of the packages.

Comment: Additionally, you may want to verify that you have a file at `javascript/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts`. If not, there could be several different causes for this, which include permissions issues, OS restrictions on creating symlinks (everything in `node_moduels/.bin` is a symlink generated on install. Could also just be that you don't have react-scripts installed... try running `npm install --save react-scripts` and see if that helps.

Comment: Moving from MacOS to Windows (Dropbox synced all the `node_modules` folder) - only deleting the folder and re-installing solved it

Comment: Yep -- thats what the above command does. Your symptom was likely due to a number of packages that perform conditional install procedures per OS. Linux, Mac, & Windows have quite a few discrepancies with a lot of fundamental project dependencies.

Comment: I've got the same problem and tried everything, and I'm already on Windows. The file's in the .bin folder and installed.

Answer (score 41):

Running these commands worked for me:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm rebuild
npm install
```

Comment: npm install => npm rebuild worked for me.  I've gotten this error with 'react-scripts' and 'next'.  It seems to happen after I delete the node_modules folder and go back to the project at a later date.

Comment: Worked for me, but `npm cache clean --force` was not necessary (node v14.17.3, npm 6.14.13). I did use `npm cache verify` instead. I'm not sure if whether or not this had an effect.

Comment: @crispengari please explain how these command works and fix the problem

Answer (score 22):

2024 answer: simply remove `node_modules` folder and run

```
npm install
```

or:

```
yarn
```

(depends on you're using `npm` or `yarn`)

it worked for me!

###### no need to do more!!!

It waste a lot of my time until I discover this, I got headache...

Comment: I just forgot to-do do this thanks

Comment: how's your head now @Raskul?

Answer (score 19):

In my situation, some problems happened with my node package. So I run `npm audit fix` and it fixed all problems

Comment: This seems the best answer so far. I migrated my code from Macbook to a PC and was unable to run my react project. "npm audit fix" solved it instantly.

Answer (score 15):

To avoid this issue to re-occur or you face this issue whenever anyone downloads your project fresh.

It's better to add this in dev dependencies using this command:

```
npm install react-scripts --save-dev
```

It will get added like this.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3"
  }
```

Do Commit and push your code.

Answer (score 14):

Faced the same problem, although I am using yarn.

The following worked for me:

```
yarn install 
yarn start
```

Answer (score 12):

Running the `npm update` command solved my problem.

Answer (score 10):

For Portable apps change

> *package.json*

as follows

```
"scripts": {

    "start": "node node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts start",
    "build": "node node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts build",
    "test": "node node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts test",
    "eject": "node node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts eject"
  }
```

Comment: Not sure why it happened, but I was able to provide explicit path to the script and it worked fine.

Answer (score 8):

To rectify this issue follow the following steps

1. run `npm install`
2. then run `npm start`

This worked fine for me

Answer (score 8):

**react-scripts** should be listed as a dependency when you run `npx create-react-app your-app`, but for some reason, it gets this error. I will list some steps that I followed that may help you fix this error:

---

First, check at your React **package.json** if there is **react-scripts** or not:
for example, you should see:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    ...
  },
```

If it's already there, now try to re-install your dependencies with `npm i`

---

If you still get the same error, try to remove your **node_modules** with `rm -rf node_modules/`, then re-install your dependencies with `npm i`

---

BUT if the package **react-scripts** wasn't in your **package.json** file, you should install it by your package manager like:
`npm i react-scripts`
then try to start your app with `npm start`

Answer (score 7):

### This is how I fix it

1. Check and Update the path variable (See below on how to update the path variable)
2. Delete node_modules and package-lock.json
3. run `npm install`
4. run `npm run start`

if this didn't work, try to install the [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) and run repair

or clean npm cache `npm cache clean --force`

### To update the path variable

1. press windows key
2. Search for `Edit the system environmental variable`
3. Click on `Environment Variables...`
4. on System variable bottom section ( there will be two section )
5. Select `Path` variable name
6. Click `Edit..`
7. Check if there is `C:\Program Files\nodejs` on the list, if not add this

Answer (score 6):

1. I uninstalled my Node.js and showed hidden files.
2. Then, I went to `C:\Users\yourpcname\AppData\Roaming\` and deleted the `npm` and `npm-cache` folders.
3. Finally, I installed a new version of Node.js.

Comment: This is not a solution really.

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue. I solved it using `npm audit fix --force`

Comment: npm audit fix --force worked for me after trying a number of solutions on this page.  I'm doing the wes bos react course and was unable to even finish the first video with this error.    Windows 10, VS Code, Node v14.17.4, npm 7.20.5

Comment: don't use this command it will break your code if you have vulnerable packages

Answer (score 6):

## React Scripts Not Recognized as internal/external script

### Step by Step Solution:

- Open Project root folder (where your package.json is located) in cmd.
- Run this script.

  ```js
  npm install react-scripts
  ```
- Clear your npm cache if necessary.

### Still Not Resolved?

- try to delete your *node_modules* and *package-lock.json* (not package.json) files, re-run npm install and restart your IDE.

```html
rd /s /q "node_modules"
del package-lock.json
del -f yarn.lock

# to clean npm cache
npm cache clean --force

# to install packages
npm install
```

- Make sure to restart your IDE and dev server if the error persists.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. I did everything which suggested here. but nothing worked. I had installed react-scripts in my node_modules also used cache but all in vain. then I just npx create-react-app and moved all my code into this new folder and all worked.

`npx create-react-app myapp`

Comment: Exactly, this method works.

Answer (score 4):

This is not recommended, so plz don't down arrow, but for troubleshooting..

**react-scripts** is not recognized as an internal or external command is related to npm.

I would update all of my dependencies in my package.json files to the latest versions in both the main directory and client directory if applicable.
You can do this by using an asterisk "*" instead of specifying a specific version number in your package.json files for your dependencies.

**For Example:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "*",
    "express": "*",
    "mongoose": "*",
    "react": "*",
    "react-dom": "*",
    "react-final-form": "*",
    "react-final-form-listeners": "*",
    "react-mapbox-gl": "*",
    "react-redux": "*",
    "react-responsive-modal": "*",
  }
```

I would then make sure any package-lock.json were deleted and then run npm install and yarn install in both the main directory and the client directory as well if applicable.

You should then be able to run a yarn build and then use yarn start to run the application.

Comment: This is bad advice. Using `*` for your version numbers is problematic because it could cause different versions of packages being installed on different systems. Use locked version numbers and update them as needed

Comment: Yea things could totally go wrong here for production purposes, but just an idea for testing purposes.

Answer (score 4):

As for me i managed to fix this issue by install this :

npm audit fix --force

and it work after that.

Answer (score 3):

Use **git bash or windows cmd** with admin rights to run **npm install** while fixing this issue, running these commands inside the editor's terminals doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

first run:

```
npm ci
```

then:

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem had to do with not having enough file permissions for some files the react-scripts package installation was going to write to. What solved it was running **git bash as an administrator** and then running `npm install --save react-scripts` again.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many of the solutions to this problem found on line, but in my case nothing worked except for reinstalling NVM for Windows (which I am using to manage multiple Node versions). In the installer, it detects installed Node versions and asks the user if they wish for NVM to control them. I said yes and NVM fixed all PATH issues. As a result, things worked as before. This issue may have multiple causes, but corrupted PATH is definitely one of them and (re)installing NVM fixes PATH.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather old question but this might be of some help for future reference. Delete node_modules folder and run npm install again. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case , I edited my files on Linux where I had node v14.0.5 installed, when I rebooted to Windows where I had node v14.0.3 I got the same error. So I updated the node version on windows and all went fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

had similar issue.. i used yarn to fix it.
i noticed that react-scripts was not found in my node modules so i decided to download it with npm but i seem to be failing too. so i tried yarn ( yarn add react-scripts) and that solved the nightmare! Hope this work for you as well. Happy debuging folks.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just re-installed the react-scripts instead of react-scripts --save.

Answer (score 0):

Started getting this error in `Azure DevOps` yesterday out of nowhere when running `npm run build`:

> 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

However when looking at `npm ci` that completed it was full of errors like:

> FetchError: Invalid response body while trying to fetch
> https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2fcompat-data: ENOENT: no such file
> or directory, lstat
> 'D:\a\1.npm_cacache\content-v2\sha512\58\0b\dc7dce0b33e86d97736b3c419005951e32af28dda3f5b8c746f16d53d4baed1dc2fd2493e9310f744696008400bf8c91ca84f9fb3ebf541ba93a541b144a'

When commenting out the cache everything started working again:

```
npm_config_cache: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.npm

- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)" | $(clientApp)\package-lock.json'
    restoreKeys: |
       npm | "$(Agent.OS)"
    path: $(npm_config_cache)
  displayName: Cache npm
```

The weird thing is that it has worked for over a year up until yesterday (2021-12-02) and we use the exact same code for caching as Microsoft has documented.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops#nodejsnpm

Noting Degraded or Unhealthy on Azure DevOps Status

https://status.dev.azure.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me,

did npm install and that didn't fix it so I simply disabled windows defender firewall and then made a fresh cloning of the repo followed by npm start. That's it!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but this worked for me in the Windows/Command prompt

`del -rf node_modules`

`yarn`

`npm start`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I tried the above thing, but that did not work some how. So,
I just typed **yarn**. And it went.

Comment: Using `yarn` was already suggested, e. g. by Raskul.

Answer (score -2):

When I make a new project using React, to install the React modules I have to run "npm install" (PowerShell) from within the new projects ClientApp folder (e.g. "C:\Users\Chris\source\repos\HelloWorld2\HelloWorld2\ClientApp"). The .NET core WebApp with React needs to have the React files installed in the correct location for React commands to work properly.

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me:

- Go to the project folder in CLI and type **npm install**.Go for a similar command if
  using yarn etc.
- Then type **npm start** if you are using Npm. Go for a similar command if using yarn
  etc.
- The file starts working

Comment: install react scripts globally `npm i -g react-scripts`