# 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, package.json, react-scripts

I am learning to react. The version I installed is 16. I installed prop-types via npm after I got an error that 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

[image]

Comment: Are you using `create-react-app`?

Comment: run npm install if you are using create-react-app

Comment: yes, i am using create-react-app, but it has been working till i installed prop-types

Comment: make it available globally. npm install -g create-react-app

Comment: that's exactly what I did and I have run npm install and it is still not working. Same error. The whole stuff was working till in installed prop-types. I have tried to uninstall it, still getting errors.

Comment: do one thing delete node_modules and package-lock.json file. and again npm install

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47928735/react-scripts-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: I'm going through a similar issue while trying to run this through my PyCharm terminal (Windows 10). I'm able to get react-scripts to run if I instead use PowerShell.

Comment: I Faced same issue ,
react-scripts is not recognized as an internal or external command,
USE THIS COMMAND:  npm i -g react-scripts

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It is an error about **react-scripts** file missing in your **node modules** directory at the time of installation.

Now, you can add manually this via the command:

> **npm install react-scripts**

Answer (score 16):

I  had the same issue, resolved by simply running following command in the project root folder -

```
npm install react-scripts --save
```

Comment: Installing react-scripts globally is not recommended by the CRA maintainers: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2436#issuecomment-306830791

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer - should it be --save

Comment: You have `react-scripts` `--save`d by default after you have used CRA. So you do not need to re-save it. If `npm install` (with or without deleting `node_modules`) doesn't fix the issue, the problem is likely with an old version of NPM or a problem with PATH which can be fixed as per my answer.

Answer (score 11):

If it doesn't get resolved even after running

```
npm install
```

OR

```
npm install react-scripts
```

Run:

```
node node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js
```

**Or use node js command-line tool and do npm install and npm start**
This solved the problem for me

Comment: Best answer, tried everything but could not get it working without directly starting

Answer (score 8):

If none of the above solutions works and you have already installed the "react-scripts" package
using

`npm install react-scripts --save`

You can try the below solution to run the application.

You should see the following in your `package.json` file

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
}
```

The script : **"start": "react-scripts start"** is linked to the 
file : `nodemon node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js`
which is used to start the project in the development env

Try to start the project directly using the below commands:

```
node node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js
```

or if you have nodemon installed then try

```
nodemon node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 5):

Simply remove **node_modules** folder and run **npm install**

Comment: it has broken everything! C:\Users\Xxxx>npm install
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'

Comment: by running npm install it will generate  node_module package with all other dependencies into it.
Goto to project path- run npm install from CLI

Answer (score 5):

I found the community answer, which is perfect solution
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue and this solution worked just fine.

run:

> npm install react-scripts

that should solve it... Enjoy!!!

Answer (score 1):

Just type `npm install` and after that run `npm start`. This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

One of the causes of this issue is corrupted PATH and the only fix I found for that issue was to (re)install NVM and let the installer take control over the installed Node version when it asks to do so and it will fix the PATH for you. In my case that was the fix.

Answer (score 0):

deleting the *node_modules* folder and the *.lock file then running `npm install` in the project directory through the terminal worked.
I tried with `yarn install` and it worked too after removing the mentioned files above.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite common problem.
Do the following steps:-

- `npm audit` The message will be like - 7 vulnerabilities (1 low, 6 high)
  You will get the vulnerabilities, and now fix it with
- `npm audit fix` or `npm audit fix --force` will prompt message like this
  removed 4 packages, changed 82 packages, and audited 1623 packages in 7s

> found 0 vulnerabilities

Problem Solved,
Happy Hacking

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by running the following command:

yarn add react-scripts

Answer (score 0):

For this error you just have to delete lock file and use command **yarn**

Answer (score 0):

You just have to install **React Script** Again.
You just need to run the command `npm i react-scripts` and then run `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

this error has happened to me in mern stack, and took around 3h to fix it:
in the end, this issue because the current node version is not the same I was used to creating the project for the first time. I hope this proposition helped someone in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Hello I'm learning the MERN stack as well(wise use of quarantine time right? )
Anyways, I'm using WINDOWS 10, and I have the same error as well.

I tried `react-scripts start` and react-scripts is not recognized as an internal command

I did a bit of googling and found out that you need to 
`npm install react-scripts -g` <- notice the -g (stands for global? I think? )

I hope this helps :>

Answer (score -1):

Just go to the Terminal and on the directory which you start your server. TYPE `npm install react-scripts`

you will be good to go

Answer (score -1):

I was trying to use 'nodemon server' then had the same error.
When I tried 'npx nodemon server', it worked.
Try to use 'npx' in front of 'npm'

Answer (score -2):

Instead of writing `react-scripts start` just write `npm start`.