# React and Bootstrap4 issue when creating application using create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using Windows 10. Follwoing are the two scenarios where I faced problems. I created applications using create-react-app command. I installed create-react-app using command `npm i -g create-react-app@1.5.2`

Scenario 1

I stopped react server which was running using npm start command. Then I installed bootstrap using `npm i bootstarp@4.1.1` and then I tried to run command npm start but rathern than starting the server, it has given an error 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command.
The application is working perfactly before I stopped the react server and installed bootstrap.

Steps to recreate the problem:

1. `create-react-app demo`
2. `cd demo`
3. `npm start` (loaded the application in browser with home page)
4. stopped the server using Ctrl + C (break)
5. `npm i bootstrap@4.1.1`
6. `npm start` (giving error 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command)

Scenario 2

I installed bootstrap in running react server using another command window / visul studio command line using `npm i bootstarp@4.1.1` and when I imported bootstrap file in index.js and saved the file. It have given error

./node_modules/style-loader/lib/addStyles.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\react\demo2\node_modules\style-loader\lib\addStyles.js'

Steps to recreate the problem:

1. `create-react-app demo`
2. `cd demo2`
3. `npm start` (loaded the application in browser with home page)
4. Open another command window and reached to location demo4 folder
5. `npm i bootstrap@4.1.1`
6. open index.js in src folder and write: `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';`
7. save the file and error comes.

Answer (score 1):

I've found many topics about this issue:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1627

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2436

['react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47928735/react-scripts-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

I think that it is related to the `npm` version that you use. It seems that npm doesn't install all the required dependencies.

Try to run `npm update` in order to update the dependencies. After this, `npm start` should work fine:

```
npm update
npm start
```