# Npm start gives me : 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.'

Tags: reactjs, npm

Here's my remote repo, I made the project with 'create-react-app':
https://github.com/mattfrancis888/project_2

Whenever I clone the project and try to launch it with npm start. It gives me:

'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.'

Why is that? I tried:

- doing 'npm i'
- npm install react-scripts --save (['react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47928735/react-scripts-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command))
- deleting and cloning the project again.

The project  works in my other computer (the desktop where I made the remote repo)

Comment: Have you checked if "node_modules/.bin/react-scripts" exists?

Comment: Delete node_modules folder, then install doing “npm install”, then run “npm run start” and it should work. Oygerwise plz post a scrrenshot of what you are executing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should solve the issue;

```
$ sudo rm -fr node_modules/ package-lock.json

$ sudo npm cache clean --force

$ sudo npm i react-scripts --unsafe-perm

$ sudo npm i --unsafe-perm
```

If still throws error,

- Change version of your NPM

Npm package versions and your environment are conflicting. Only way to fix  is installing different versions and trying to find compatible environment to run your app.

Comment: This worked for me, and this was as a result of upgraded npm version ii did some days back.