# .react-scripts start : 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-scripts

I working in an object detection model and I have linked it with the frontend which I created using react.
while running the command npm start I found this error.[i have shared an image for the error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkZ53.png)

Comment: Hi friend, it seems to be duplicated question. 
Please check it out: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54403797/9863596)
Good luck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47928735/react-scripts-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 0):

This error comes mostly when **react-scripts** is not present in node modules directory.

Try manually adding react-scripts : "**npm install react-scrips --save**".

If still facing issues, try running "**npm audit fix**". It mostly fixes this issue.