# How Can I Download a React Project from Github and Run in My Laptop

Tags: reactjs, github, download, project

I am new to Javascript and React. I was wondering if there is any way I can download some open-source projects written in React JS from GitHub and run them on my laptop with the help of sublime text. I was thinking to study the source code so that I can learn React.
I found some projects in Github but not sure how I can download the source code and run it.
Is there any step-by-step guideline? Can anyone help?

when I go to run an npm start on it, I get this error:

E:\Sem 04\Software project\React App\test001>npm start

> education-academia@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47928735/react-scripts-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: Do you want to know how to set up a GitHub project in your lap, right?

Answer (score 0):

[image: github repo clone]

1. you can copy that HTTPS link then in your console - `git clone copied_url` for this u have to [install git](https://github.com/git-guides/install-git) in your lap
2. You can download a zip file => and extract that

after any of the methods, open the project folder => then console => `npm install` or `yarn install` (this installs all the project dependencies)