# I am facing an issue in start a git repo in my local host sever

Tags: reactjs, server, localhost, repository, npm-start

How to start react repo  project server in local host

PS C:\Users\ERAFZ\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\e-commerce_React>
npm start

> finalproject@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
PS C:\Users\ERAFZ\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\e-commerce_React>  npm run dev
npm ERR! Missing script: "dev"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\ERAFZ\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-12-27T20_54_25_256Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\ERAFZ\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\e-commerce_React>
npm start

> finalproject@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
PS C:\Users\ERAFZ\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\e-commerce_React>

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47928735/react-scripts-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are getting `react-scripts` is not recognized, tells me that you have not installed that NPM in your project.  It is likely that you need to simply run `npm install` and it will be installed for you.

You haven't said how your React project was created.  Are you using Create-React-App (CRA), or possibly using Vite, or some other tool?

If this is a new project, then you likely do NOT want to use CRA.  It is now deprecated. My recommendation would be to use Vite (you would simply run `npx create-vite@latest` and follow the prompts for creating a new React project).

---

Note: when you run `npm start` or `npm run XXX`, NPM reads your project's `package.json` file and looks at the `script` section to determine what commands to run on your computer for `start` or `XXX`.  If you get errors, then it is typically that your project or your computer do not have the appropriate software installed to run that `script`.

Comment: _"Are you using Create-React-App (CRA), or possibly using Vite, or some other tool?"_... `react-scripts` is only used by CRA

Comment: I know...but I wanted them to go through the logic path themselves.  They want to be aware that this is important information when talking about "a new project".